# How do I add a copy constructor and assignment operator to this class?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having trouble adding a copy constructor to this class:
http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

I need to add it so that I can add the concurrent_queue in an stl vector container.
Tried the below, and it almost compiles.  In fact, if I remove the_mutex and the_condition_variable from the copy constructor it compiles.  When I add it back in it doesn't.  The assignment operator seems to be OK with regards to compilation.

```
concurrent_queue(concurrent_queue<Data> const& rhs):
    the_queue(rhs.the_queue),
    the_mutex(rhs.the_mutex),
    the_condition_variable(rhs.the_condition_variable)
{
}

concurrent_queue<Data>& operator = (concurrent_queue<Data> const& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs) return *this; // check for self assignment

    the_queue = rhs.the_queue;
    the_mutex(rhs.the_mutex);
    the_condition_variable(rhs.the_condition_variable);
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
concurrentqueue.h: In copy constructor ‘concurrent_queue<Data>::concurrent_queue(const concurrent_queue<Data>&) [with Data = Packet*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_construct.h:74:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, const _T2&) [with _T1 = concurrent_queue<Packet*>, _T2 = concurrent_queue<Packet*>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:187:   instantiated from ‘static void std::__uninitialized_fill_n<<anonymous> >::uninitialized_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = concurrent_queue<Packet*>*, _Size = long unsigned int, _Tp = concurrent_queue<Packet*>, bool <anonymous> = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:223:   instantiated from ‘void std::uninitialized_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = concurrent_queue<Packet*>*, _Size = long unsigned int, _Tp = concurrent_queue<Packet*>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:318:   instantiated from ‘void std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&, std::allocator<_Tp2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = concurrent_queue<Packet*>*, _Size = long unsigned int, _Tp = concurrent_queue<Packet*>, _Tp2 = concurrent_queue<Packet*>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:1035:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_initialize(size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = concurrent_queue<Packet*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<concurrent_queue<Packet*> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:230:   instantiated from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_t, const _Tp&, const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = concurrent_queue<Packet*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<concurrent_queue<Packet*> >]’
test.cpp:18:   instantiated from here
concurrentqueue.h:24: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::mutex) (boost::mutex&)’
```

EDIT:
It seems that boost mutex inherits non-copyable and condition variable I think is the same.
The interesting thing is that in the assignment I'm able to copy it.  Why would that even compile?  Do I need to worry about the fact that it's non-copyable in practice for the situation I'm using it for?

Comment: There was no need to write either of those: the compiler would have emitted code to copy member-wise anyway, if it was legal. What you needed to do was write *legal* code, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `boost::mutex` and `boost::condition_variable` only have default constructors. Aside from that, you don't want their (potentially locked) state to be copied - just use the default constructors.

Also you shouldn't copy `the_queue` directly as this is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `boost::mutex` and `boost::condition` are not copyable (and there is no meaning to copying a mutex lock anyways). Construct them using the default constructor in your copy constructor as follows:

```
concurrent_queue(concurrent_queue<Data> const& rhs):
    the_queue(rhs.the_queue),
    the_mutex(),
    the_condition_variable()
{
}
```

Note that there are [problems](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/07/125032.php) with making the copy constructor thread safe. If you're not copying objects between threads, that shouldn't be a problem, though. Following the idea in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065847/how-do-i-insert-queue-elements-into-a-vector/4065859#4065859), where all `concurrent_queue`objects are pre-allocated, this shouldn't be a problem.